# How to get RSS info from link and print it in PHP/HTML page?

Tags: php, html, rss

I have never worked before with RSS.

I have tried to print it with `<iframe>` but it was a silly try.

I am well familiar with PHP/CSS/HTML and I want to know how I can print the RSS info in HTML/PHP page from this RSS link:

```
http://grabo.bg/rss/?city=&affid=16090
```

Do i need any parser or something? Please tell me how I can print this content in html form?

What i have to know about RSS?

Comment: Have you ever googled about RSS before? RSS is basically just XML. You could use SimpleXML in PHP to parse it. But I bet, that there are many other libraries existing in PHP just to handle RSS feeds.

Answer (score 0):

it is just xml. All you have to do is curl that page or:

```
$feed = file_get_contents('http://grabo.bg/rss/?city=&affid=16090');
```

And after that to say:

```
$rss = simplexml_load_string($feed);
```

and then say

```
foreach($rss as $r){

//in your case
echo $r->title;
echo $r->content;

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's working very well!
Can you tell me how i can get more detailed parts of the content so i can make for the nice HTML/CSS form. I want to add CSS effects on the parsed info.

Comment: No I can not. All you got is in answer.